# Entity Framework Join multiple tables is slow

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, frameworks, entity

first time I was trying to join this many tables using Entity Framework.

Everything works well but loading time is about 1 minute, very bad. I dont know if is some different solution to join this many tables, or something what could help.

It is about 5000 records in database. I think in future number of this records can be more higher. I need something what will take it. Thanks.

Code below:

```
var JoinedTopCars = db.CustomerAdvertisement.Where(o => o.Top == true)
 .Join(
db.CarManufacturerName,
n => n.CarManufacturerId,
q => q.CarManufacturerId,
(n, q) => new
{
    n,
    q,
})
 .Join(
db.CarManufacturerModel,
o => o.n.CarModelId,
j => j.CarModelId,
(o, j) => new
{
    j,
    o,
}).Where(y => y.j.CarManufacturerId == y.o.q.CarManufacturerId)
.Join(
db.TypeOFFuel,
e => e.o.n.FuelId,
r => r.Id,
(e, r) => new
{
    e,
    r,
})
.Join(
db.TypeOFGearBox,
t => t.e.o.n.GearBoxId,
i => i.Id,
(t, i) => new
{
    t,
    i,
})
.Join(
db.Country,
y => y.t.e.o.n.CountryOfOrigin,
u => u.Id,
(y, u) => new
{
    y,
    u,
})
 .Join(
db.TypeOFChassis,
c => c.y.t.e.o.n.ChassisId,
d => d.Id,
(c, d) => new
{
    c,
    d,
})
.Join(
db.CarDoors,
e => e.c.y.t.e.o.n.CarDoorsId,
f => f.Id,
(e, f) => new
{
    e,
    f,
})
.Join(
db.TypOfMovement,
g => g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.MovementId,
f => f.Id,
(g, f) => new
{
    g,
    f,
})
.Join(
db.Area,
i => i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.AreaOfOrigin ?? 0,
f => f.Id,
(i, f) => new
{
    i,
    f,
})
.Join(
db.District,
j => j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.OkresOfOrigin ?? 0,
f => f.Id,
(j, f) => new
{
    j,
    f,
})
.Join(
db.CarColor,
k => k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.CarColorId,
x => x.Id,
(k, x) => new JoinedTopCars
{
    Id = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Id,
    Objem = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.cm3,
    Carname = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.q.CarName,
    CarModel = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.j.CarModel,
    Typ = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.ModelType,
    Color = x.ColorName,
    Karoseria = k.j.i.g.e.d.ChassisName,
    Dvere = k.j.i.g.f.NumberOfDoors,
    Pohon = k.j.i.f.Movement,
    VIN = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.VIN,
    Metalic = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Metalic,
    Poskodene = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Crashed,
    Pojazdne = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Drivable,
    DPH = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.DPH,
    Leasing = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Leasing,
    Emisie = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Emmisions,
    Spotreba = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Consumption,
    Km = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.KM,
    Rok = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.DateOfOrigin.ToString(),
    Vykon = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.HP,
    Palivo = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.r.Fuel,
    Prevodovka = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.i.GearBox,
    Krajina = k.j.i.g.e.c.u.CountryName,
    Okres = k.f.DistrictName,
    Kraj = k.j.f.AreaName,
    Vybava = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Equipment,
    Popis = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Description,
    Kontakt = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.ContInfo,
    ZobrazMeno = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.ShowName,
    ZobrazCislo = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.ShowPhone,
    Cena = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.Price,
    TitleImage = k.j.i.g.e.c.y.t.e.o.n.TitlePhoto,
})
.OrderByDescending(z => z.Id)
.Take(15);
```

EDIT: I make what @romfir write bellow and decrase loading time from 1 minute to 3 sec.

1. Create SQL view
   [image]
2. insert SQL query with JOINed tables (if you expect empty value use LEFT JOIN)
3. Update ADO.NET EF model, .edmx file
4. use this SQL View simmilar like table

Comment: You can try to create a simmilar View in the database, it will work faster, because databse engine will optimize it.

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create [View](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-views/sql-server-create-view/) in the database, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view_name
AS
SELECT
    CustomerAdvertisement.ID as CustomerAdvertisementID -- 'as Name' is optional
    CustomerAdvertisement.cm3
    -- other columns You want to include
FROM 
    CustomerAdvertisement
JOIN CarManufacturerName 
    on CarManufacturerName.CarManufacturerId = CustomerAdvertisement.CarManufacturerId
JOIN SomeTable
    on some_condition
-- other joins

WHERE
    CustomerAdvertisement.Top = true
    and other_conditions
```

After creating view that matches Your criteria, You can [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) it, and then use in Your code.

Comment: WOW ! Extreme difference, from 1 minute of loading to 3 sec :) thanks I will post tutorial to my question.